# HXS filtering with scrapy - python

Tags: python, select, filter, scrapy

I'm new in this sphere and i need more information. I couldn't find any information in the Internet. For example now now i use this function `hxs.select('//div[@id="CategoryBreadcrumb"]//text()').extract()` . In this `div` I have `ul` and `li`s with `a`nchors in each `li` but one. I need the text from the `li` that doesn't have `a` tag in it. I'd be thankful if you give any educational links for hxs filtering as well. Thanks in advance!
Here is an example if u cant visualize what i need.

```
<div id='CategoryBreadcrumb'>
<ul>
  <li><a href=#>I dont need</a></li>
  <li><a href=#>I dont need</a></li>
  <li><a href=#>I dont need</a></li>
  <li>Text that i need</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make the question a bit more specific? Focus on he example you showed, but without the "educational links" bit and this would be a good question I think. Soliciting links or asking people to write complete tutorials isn't great, but it looks like you have a specific question you care about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
hxs.select('//div[@id = "CategoryBreadcrumb"]/ul/li/text()')
```

To learn more about XPaths see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) for the basics, and [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for the full specification.

---

PS: scrapy uses lxml. You can test your XPaths using code like this:

```
import lxml.html as LH

text = '''
<div id='CategoryBreadcrumb'>
<ul>
  <li><a href=#>I dont need</a></li>
  <li><a href=#>I dont need</a></li>
  <li><a href=#>I dont need</a></li>
  <li>Text that i need</li>
</ul>
</div>
'''

doc = LH.fromstring(text)
print(doc.xpath('//div[@id = "CategoryBreadcrumb"]/ul/li/text()'))

# ['Text that i need']
```

Comment: Thanks! would u recommend (if there is such) M Fire Fox addon - wich generates xpaths expressions?

Comment: With [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) addon, if you click on the `HTML` toolbar button, a tree representing the HTML will be displayed below. If you right-click on an element a menu will pop up with the menu item "Copy XPath", which stores the XPath in the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try scrapy shell command with following:
`scrapy shell "http://yourdomain.com"`
and you will get a python shell with various ready to use variables including hxs(HtmlXPathSelector). 
Test your xpath there.